# Passing a function as a parameter

Tags: c

Is there any way to pass function as a parameter when starting a program in C? I am implementing an app for integral approximation, and all I need is to type a function I want to work with when starting the application.  I tried (e.g.) `2/(2+2*x)`, but I only get back "2". When I write to application directly, there is no problem. Is there any simple way of getting this?  Maybe redistribute it to more parameters? Like

```
app.c number number*x number *x*x number *x*x*x... ?
```

Thanks

Comment: you can parse expression, generate syntax tree and evaluate it.  it aint simple.

Comment: Have a look at [GNU bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison)

Comment: This has nothing to do with MPI, tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to go about this would be to store your expression in a file, give your program that file's name as an argument, and then use `system()` or an equivalent to have the shell interpret and evaluate the expression at runtime. This will be fairly slow however.

If you want more performance, and your functions aren't terribly complicated (e.g. you only have basic arithmetic operations), then you could write a recursive function to evaluate it. Starting from the end of the formula, walk backwards and find the operation with the lowest precedence. Recursively evaluate both sides, then apply the operation to the results. If you can't find an operator, check for parentheses around your expression, and evaluate the insides. If there are no parentheses either, then the entire expression is a single value, and can be converted to a double (ostensibly).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in expression evaluator in C. If you only need simple expressions, and the syntax is not that important you could use *reverse polish notation*, as used by HP calculators way back. This system use a stack, entering a number pushes it on the stack, entering an operations pops values from the stack, calculates, and push them back. There is no need to handle parentheses, as expressions are typically written inside out.

For example, 2*x would be written as:

```
app 2 x mul
```

For example, your original expression could be written as:

```
app 2 2 2 x mul add div
```

I leave the implementation as an exercise, you should not need more than a page of code for this.

Comment: As for me this notation is handy only when you want to parse expression and interpret it in one pass. But we expecting that expression will always contain variable which will be substituted later we have to build expression tree, so actual interpretation on parse will be combining sub-trees stored in the stack with each `mul`, `add` etc. But using lisp-like or just reverse-reverse polish notation will be easely parsed to single-rooted tree of final expression (i.e. "div 2 add 2 mul 2 x", where each word will require zero or more arguments which is taken right after it, without any stack)

Comment: This can absolutely be used in a two-pass environment. The first would build up a expression tree, the second would evaluate the tree bottom-up. You could store constants and variables in the tree and assign values to variables in the second pass.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I just say that it is more suitable for single-pass evaluation like in Forth language. Stack is nice way for combining, but that will require implementation. In original question there is only need in expression that can be evaluated. So no need to implement some argument/result passing convention between some small snippets of logic. It's easier to build exp. tree just as it is. BTW, you can avoid second pass if you'll not use `x` as placeholder but expect that "program" passed to programm will use value from top of the stack (of course you'll need additional words)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. Just to show that it isn't so complicated:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct expr_s {
    char op;
    struct expr_s *exprA, *exprB;
    float value;
} expr;

int readExpr(expr *node, int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int argn = 1;
    assert(argc > 0);
    switch(argv[0][0]) {
    case '0' ... '9':
    case '-': case '.':
        node->op = '#'; // direct value
        node->value = atof(argv[0]);
        return 1;
    case 'x':
        if (argv[0][1] == '\0') { // variable
            node->op = 'x';
            return 1;
        }
        break;
    default: ;
    }
    // binary expr
    if (strcmp(argv[0], "mul") == 0) node->op = '*';
    else if (strcmp(argv[0], "add") == 0) node->op = '+';
    else if (strcmp(argv[0], "div") == 0) node->op = '/';
    else if (strcmp(argv[0], "sub") == 0) node->op = '-';
    else abort();
    node->exprA = (expr*)malloc(sizeof(expr));
    node->exprB = (expr*)malloc(sizeof(expr));
    argn += readExpr(node->exprA, argc-argn, argv+argn);
    argn += readExpr(node->exprB, argc-argn, argv+argn);
    return argn;
}

float evalExpr(expr *node, float x) {
    switch(node->op) {
    case '#': return node->value;
    case 'x': return x;
    case '*': return (evalExpr(node->exprA, x) * evalExpr(node->exprB, x));
    case '+': return (evalExpr(node->exprA, x) + evalExpr(node->exprB, x));
    case '/': return (evalExpr(node->exprA, x) / evalExpr(node->exprB, x));
    case '-': return (evalExpr(node->exprA, x) - evalExpr(node->exprB, x));
    default: abort();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    expr rootExpr;
    float x;
    readExpr(&rootExpr, argc-1, argv+1);
    for(x=0; x < 5; x+=0.5) {
        printf("f(%f) = %f\n", x, evalExpr(&rootExpr, x));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Rusult:

```
./playground div 2 add 2 mul 2 x
f(0.000000) = 1.000000
f(0.500000) = 0.666667
f(1.000000) = 0.500000
f(1.500000) = 0.400000
f(2.000000) = 0.333333
f(2.500000) = 0.285714
f(3.000000) = 0.250000
f(3.500000) = 0.222222
f(4.000000) = 0.200000
f(4.500000) = 0.181818
```

Note that if you'll use the reverse polish notation you'll see almost the same, but with stack of `expr` instead if subsequent call of `readExpr`.